# Split Python list into custom chunk size based on second list

Tags: python, list, slice

I am looking for a way to split a list into predefined slices:

```
a = list(range(1, 1001)) # Added list() 
b = [200, 500, 300]
```

List `a` should be sliced into `len(b)` sublists containing the first 200 elements of a, the following 500, and the last 300. It is safe to assume that `sum(b) == len(a)`.

Is there a common function for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an iterator from the list (if it isn't one already) and get `n` times  the `next` element from the iterator for each `n` in `b`.

```
>>> a = range(1, 1001)
>>> b = [200, 500, 300]
>>> a_iter = iter(a)
>>> [[next(a_iter) for _ in range(n)] for n in b]
[[1,
  2,
  ...
  199,
  200],
 [201,
  ...
  700],
 [701,
  702,
  ...
  999,
  1000]]
```

Comment: Solved, I'll accept in 5 minutes once the system allows it :).

Comment: You would need a default value on `next` to avoid an exception if the chunks are larger than the content of `a`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to consume an iterator of `a` in the predefined chunks:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> b = [200, 500, 300]
>>> a = range(1, 1001)
>>> it  = iter(a)
>>> [list(islice(it, i)) for i in b]
```

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

a = range(1, 1001)
b = [200, 500, 300]

c = iter(a)
results = [list(islice(c, length)) for length in b]
```

`islice` behaves like slice, except that slice takes sequence and returns sequence, whereas `islice` takes iterable and returns iterable.

Iterators are "disposable" -- once you extract element from it, it's no longer there, and next element becomes new first element.